# Horizontal progressbar with circle indicators

Tags: android, android-view, android-styles, android-progressbar

I'm working on an app that should have a progressbar like this:

[image]

Now the issue im facing is how can I create the circles in this progress bar, is it possible to do such thing?

Comment: Create this Image with transparent circle and horizontal bar ... after that fill with green color with ProgresssBar (Custom)

Comment: @AM your comment brought me to the sollution, simple yet it does the work. Thinking outside the box, nice! Submit your answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2):

One great tutorial is there in Git, Check this :
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Progress-Bar-Custom-View